# How to play UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to find a way to play default notification sound and i can't :)
I mean just play (AVAudioPlayer, AudioToolbox, e.t.c.) this sound. 
Anyone can help? :)

Comment: The question could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277811/play-local-notification-default-sound-when-displaying-uialertview

Comment: Nope, it's not. The point is to play _current_ default sound, which can be changed in the future.

Comment: Still no answer? Im having the same issue. I want to play UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName when app is in background as well as when notification fires and app is in foreground

Answer (score 1):

If you want jus to play default sound for notification use :

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1315);

In link below is the list of codes of system sounds
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices