# UNNotification not playing alert sound while inside the App

Tags: ios, audio

While user swithcing to ios screen , the Alert coming up with Sound.
But while inside the App it self , only Alert msg poped up , but no Sound.

How to solve this proble, ? I want Alert+Sound while user inside the App too.

Comment: Are you scheduling local notification ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play local notification default sound when displaying UIAlertView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277811/play-local-notification-default-sound-when-displaying-uialertview)